# Who is my friend's favorite writer

Tags: cipher

I one day asked my friend who his favorite writer is and he responded with a puzzle, writing something on a piece of paper that **looks like**:

```
3Zll3Zll-Z73C
```

I need your help. Who is my friend's favorite writer?

---

Hint 1 (Edited, sorry about the typo)

> One famous work by the writer is known by the quote,
>      `SA=SA>O=O`

Hint 2

> My friend is working in the department of chemistry as a programmer

Hints 3-5 (added after @Alconja posted the accepted answer)

> 1337, Mendeleev, C2Kelvin

Comment: Welcome on puzzling.SE! I've taken the liberty of changing the tag - according to the tag description, "A riddle gives indirect clues about an unnamed object or concept to be identified. It is often presented in the form of a poem." The pattern tag seems to be a better fit.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about the tags well enough although I have read through a few riddles on the site.

Comment: Is the first hint encoded the same way as the writer's name ?

Comment: It's good that you asked. The answer is no.

Comment: @Lolgast Don't you think the [tag:cipher] tag may be better than the [tag:pattern] tag?

Comment: @Weijun - You've accepted my answer, but it's still not 100% complete... Don't feel like you have to give the tick to an incomplete solution.

Comment: (or if you're happy because it's close enough, and the gaps are trivial, feel free to edit my answer and add in the missing parts)

Comment: I haven't thought of editing. I intended to post my own answer ... but editing seems a good choice too. Do you mind if I mark the edited answer as community owned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well the answer is almost certainly:

> George Orwell

But I'm not 100% sure how the cipher works...

My reasoning:

> Firstly, there's a *mostly* one to one correspondence between letters in the cipher text and plain text:
>
>  `3Zll3Zll-Z73C`
>  `GEORGEORWELL`
>
>  `3` => `G`, `Z` => `E`, `ll` => `OR`, though it slightly breaks down towards the end...
>
>  Secondly, the hint (`SA=SA>O=O`) appears to be referring to the [Animal Farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Farm) quote:
>         *"All animals are equal but some animals are more equal than others"*
>  Since **S**ome **A**nimals are more (`>`) equal (`=`) than **O**thers...

Comment: It looks like the whole cipher is done in pairs (3Z)(ll)(3Z)(ll)(-Z7)(3C), and may relate to hint 2.

Comment: The double ell sure _looks like_ `||`, the logical OR operator from C and languages with a similar syntax. Perhaps the other "glyphs" look like something (possibly from chemistry) that explains the encoding, too.

Comment: @MOehm - Makes a lot of sense... though I don't see any other symbols either.

Comment: 3Z might be in fact 32, which is the number of the Germanium element (Ge)

Comment: @FlorianBourse good spotting, which means the -Z73C could be referring to absolute zero, though I'm not sure how that converts to "well"... Perhaps some other scientific term I'm not aware of...

Comment: @Alconja Good one! -273C is exactly 0K (Celsius degree to kelvins) ! Which could be read OK ;)

Answer (score 5):

With the final hint the cypher is

> 1337 - use leetspeak
>  Mendeleev - refer to the periodic table
>  C2Kelvin - that's Celcius temperature
>
>  Now, 3Zll3Zll-Z73C becomes 32 || 32 || -273C, by substituting symbols with the shape of the letters. The element with atomic number 32 is germanium (Ge). The || symbol is 'logical or' in c-like programming syntax. And -273C is 0K, which translates into Well.
>
>  So your friend wrote Ge OR Ge OR Well,
>  George Orwell.

Comment: Perfect! I have upvoted but since Alconja is the first to get the answer without the additional hints, I will leave it as the accepted one. Thank you again for your interest and participation!